Cannot import stuff from tensorflow.keras
I have every package installed (tensorflow, keras, sci-kit, etc.).
I cannot use the stuff from
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

I have this code from ChatGPT (because I couldn't find any other way of getting this stuff from other sources). But I get these errors:
Unresolved reference 'ImageDataGenerator'
Unresolved reference 'VGG16'
Unresolved reference 'Sequential'

So how do I make this work?

This is not an actual issue, the code will run, its just that tensorflow is confusing for IDE autocomplete engines.

It seems like your IDE cannot find those packages.
Running:
pip show tensorflow

Can verify wether or not you have the packages in your environment. If it isnt, try reinstalling the packages.
I would opt for a virtual environment:
python -m venv new_venv
.\new_venv\Scripts\activate  # asumming you are on windows
pip install tensorflow


Where am I supposed to run that command? I am using PyCharm, and I tried it in the "Python Console" tab:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
..........
File "", line 1
pip show tensorflow
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am trying to fix this issue for like 2 hours now, it's very frustrating that I can't find any working fix..
